# Ruby on rails how to make website that doesn't refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not even sure how to ask my question.

I know the basics of ruby on rails and I can make a web app. but I now have a project where I want to have a button on a view that sends data to the controller, but I don't want the controller to send me to a different view, instead I want it to send data back to me (maybe in Json format) and populate something in the view with that data retrieved from the database.

Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing it? What tools do I need if this kind of functionality isn't built into rails itself? I don't know anything about it but could ajax help?

Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make it with javascript.

In your case I advise you to use a simple ajax request with jQuery.
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Jquery is a javascript library that allow you to do this.

1) Include jquery in your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) Make the ajax query:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/api/your_url",
  data: {
    test: "parameter send to the rails controller and stored into params"
  },
  success: function( data ) {
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: as a novice I found this to be very helpful in understanding the above code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEYx8dQr_cQ

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/). You can use [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) in your client side javascript to send an asynchronous request to the server and register a callback function that will be called on the client when the server responds. In the callback function you can update your webpage with the new information.